# How did x become -sqrt(x^2)?

Tags: limits, radicals

> In computing the limit as $x \to -\infty$, we must remember that for $x<0$, we have $\sqrt{x^2} = |x| = -x$. So when we divide the numerator by $x<0$, we get
>   $$
> \frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}{x}
>  = \frac{\sqrt{2x^2+1}}{-\sqrt{x^2}}
>  = - \sqrt{\frac{2x^2+1}{x^2}}
>  = - \sqrt{2 + \frac{1}{x^2}}
> $$

How did the denominator change from $x$ to $-\sqrt{x^2}$ ? I can't seem to understand.

I'm mainly confused by where the negative came from.

Comment: Hint: the $\sqrt{}$ symbol always means the *positive* square root.  But here $x$ is negative...

Comment: $x$ is negative so $-|x| = x$ and $\sqrt{x^2} = |x|$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because we are looking at the limit $x\rightarrow-\infty,$ our target is negative x from the limit's perspective. That means since the value $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|$ (you can confirm this by doing casework on positive and negative values - note that square roots are always positive!), $\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x$ since $|x|=-x$ for negative x.

(since $-x=\sqrt{x^2}$ we can negate both sides to get $x=-\sqrt{x^2}$)

Comment: But how does |x| = -x show that it's $-\sqrt(x)^2$? I'm still not seeing something here

Comment: That cleared it up thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

For $x<0$ $$\sqrt{x^2}=|x|=-x,$$ 
which says $x=-\sqrt{x^2}.$